# air seamless install with native installer

Tags: flash, air

Air allows for [seamless installs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_badge_install.html) (aka, "badge installs") from the browser, as well as [launching an Air app](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=distributing_apps_3.html) from the browser.  Air 2.0 has the [Native Process API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html), which requires packing the app as an .exe/.dmg rather than a .air file.

My question: does the badge install process support seamless installation of native Air installers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you can.

from the comments on [this blog post](http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2010/01/application_update_security_an.html)

> 3) If the user installs an AIR
>   application via .dmg/.exe, is it
>   possible to launch the application
>   from the seamless install badge on a
>   web page? ... [No, the
>   seamless install badge also does not
>   work with native application
>   installers. —Oliver]

Although, if you do want to retain updating functionality as well, there is a project on google code called nativeapplicationupdater